# Disabling responsiveness and Column ordering

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some problems with column ordering after disabling responsiveness in Bootstrap 3.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-push-3">...</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-pull-9">...</div>
</div>
```

If i do so, it affect layout on resolution below 1024 - blocks change places.
I've tried another solutions, like this one...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-push-3">...</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-pull-9">...</div>
</div>
```

... and this one...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">...</div>
</div>
```

... and none of them work properly.

I just want to disable responsiveness and force col-9 block go first in HTML document and col-3 go after it at any resolution, but col-3 block (sidebar) must be aligned left and col-9 block (main content) must be aligned right.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also read  http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive and /or  try maybe. https://github.com/bassjobsen/non-responsive-tb3. Using the col-xs-* classes seems right (cause they never stack). The xs grid don't have pull, push and offset classes.

Add an float right seems a solution in your case:

```
<div class="container" style="background-color:white;">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9" style="background-color:red;float:right;">Right</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color:yellow;">Left</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9" style="background-color:green;">Right</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color:blue;">Left</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Floats works just fine. But, it's strange, that after disabling responsiveness i can't push/pull columns properly. Anyway, thanks for help! Problem has solved.

Comment: See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options. Column ordering is n/a for the xs-grid. You will have to compile your own version to add it or use https://github.com/bassjobsen/non-responsive-tb3